# Socket Programming file upload issues?Complete file not uploading

Tags: java, android, sockets, file-upload

Hi i am using the following code for uploding my file from android phone to the server bt the file does not upload completely..e.g i uploded a `11kb` file and got only `8kb` file  at the server.What am i doing wrong?

Client  side

```
Socket skt = new Socket"112.***.*.**", 3000);   

                String FileName=fil.getName();  

                            PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(skt.getOutputStream())),true);                     
                out2.println("Upload");
                out2.println(FileName);         
                out2.println(spinindx); 
                out2.println(singleton.arrylst_setngs.get(0).toString());
                out2.println(singleton.arrylst_setngs.get(1).toString());               
                out2.println(singleton.arrylst_setngs.get(2).toString());
                out2.println(singleton.arrylst_setngs.get(3).toString());
                out2.println(singleton.arrylst_setngs.get(4).toString());

                out2.flush();
                //Create a file input stream and a buffered input stream.
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fil);
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());

                //Write the file to the server socket           
                int i;          
                byte[] buf = new byte[512];

                while ((i = in.read(buf)) != -1) {                  
                    out.write(buf,0,i);

                    publishProgress(in.available());
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                //Close the writers,readers and the socket.
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();                
                out2.close();               
                skt.close();
            }
            catch( Exception e ) {              
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

The server side

```
InputStream inStream = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader inm = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

                String Request=inm.readLine();  
if(Request.equals("Upload")){

                    fileName = inm.readLine();
                    chosn = inm.readLine();
                    lt=inm.readLine();
                    cs = inm.readLine();                                    
                    om = inm.readLine();
                    o = inm.readLine();
                    check=inm.readLine();                   



                    //Read, and write the file to the socket
                    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);         
                    int i=0;                    
                    File f=new File("D:/data/"+filePrefx+fileName);
                    if(!f.exists()){
                        f.createNewFile();

                    }
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/data/"+filePrefx+fileName);
                    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                    byte[] buf = new byte[512];

                    while ((i = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        out.write(buf,0,i);
                        System.out.println("Receiving data...");
                    }


                    in.close(); 
                    inStream.close();
                    out.close();    
                    fos.close();
                                        socket.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using both a BufferedReader and a BufferedInputStream on the same underlying socket at the server side, and two kinds of output stream/writer at the client. So your BufferedReader is buffering, which is what it's supposed to do, and thus 'stealing' some of the data you're expecting to read with the BufferedInputStream. Moral: you can't do that. Use DataInputStream & DataOutputStream only, and writeUTF()/readUTF() for the 8 lines you are reading from the client before the file.

Comment: so plz tell me what should i do?

Comment: @Harinder I told you what to do above. See my last sentence. @user658991 actually I am right indeed. You can delete your misleading comments.

Comment: @Harinder this is not a coding service. I've provided quite enough information for you to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You shared the same underlying InputStream between your BufferedReader and bufferedInputStream.

What happened is, when you do the reading through BufferedReader, it reads more than the a few lines you requested from the underlying InputStream into its own internal buffer. And when you create the BufferedInputStream, the data has already been read by the BufferedReader. So Apart from what EJP suggested not to use any buffered class, you can create the BufferedInputStream, and then create the Reader on Top of it. The code is something like this:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);
Reader inm = new InputStreamReader(in);
```

Add it to the beginning of your server code and remove this line:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);
```

Comment: See this, i never tried though

  void read() throws IOException {
    log("Reading from file.");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fFileName), fEncoding);
    try {
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        text.append(scanner.nextLine() + NL);
      }
    }
    finally{
      scanner.close();
    }
    log("Text read in: " + text);
  }

Copied from
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

Answer (score -1):

See this, i never tried though

```
  void read() throws IOException {
    log("Reading from file.");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fFileName), fEncoding);
    try {
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        text.append(scanner.nextLine() + NL);
      }
    }
    finally{
      scanner.close();
    }
    log("Text read in: " + text);
  }
```

Shamelessly copied from
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42

Comment: Ya,harinder is totally right. The problem lies more in the way you mix up the text info with the binary data. I think there's 3 solutions:

1.Send your meta data as binary and break them up using some special characters, but in that case you'll have to handle the encoding issues yourself

2.Encode the data you want to send into pure text like how email deal with its attachment using MIME coding but it gonna transfer more data than it need.

3.Mark the end of text data with an special mark and read them all out at once and break it up later.